# Access vba datasheet form new columns

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access-2016

I have a data sheet form linked to a table. Somtimes the table gets new fields. How can I update the form with vba so I get the new filelds in the form also.

Comment: Can you give a little more information, what is the data sheet source, is it the table name, select * from tablename or something else.  `.requery` may help

Comment: I use the function in Access, open the table and then use Create, Forms, Datasheet from the meny. (Requrey only renew the data not add columns.)

Comment: Try saving the form and then using select * from table for the source, as shown in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsource